# Query DynamoDB with IN Clause

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and wanted to know how can we query on a table in DynamoDB with IN clause using Java.

I have a table named `items.` It`s schema is

```
1. Product (Partition Key of type String)
2. ID (Sort Key of type int)
3. Date ( attribute of type String)
```

I want to query similar to

```
SELECT ID FROM items WHERE Product IN ("apple","orange").
```

or

```
SELECT Product FROM items WHERE ID IN (100,200).
```

Comment: That is in JavaScript, I need it in Java

Comment: Do you really think an SQL query is different following the language you use to send it ? Maybe the way you'll build the query can change, but SQL will stay SQL. If you're familiar with Criteria this will help => http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html If you're not aware about criteria, I recommend you to read about it.

Comment: @Zorglube The link you gave doesn't answer his question. It doesn't show you how to do an IN clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the requirement is to get the products without the partition key, there are two options available.

1) Create GSI (Global Secondary Index) on sort key attribute **`Id`** to use the Query API

2) Scan the entire table to get the products - not very efficient as it scans the full table

Both the options use the **IN operator** available on DynamoDB.

**Sample code for Scan using ID:-**

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<>();
attributeValues.put(":id1", new AttributeValue().withN("100"));
attributeValues.put(":id2", new AttributeValue().withN("200"));

DynamoDBScanExpression dynamoDBScanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                                                    .withFilterExpression("ID IN (:id1, :id2)")
                                                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(attributeValues);


PaginatedScanList<yourModelClass> scanList = dynamoDBMapper.scan(yourModelClass.class, dynamoDBScanExpression,
        new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT));

Iterator<yourModelClass> iterator = scanList.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().getTitle());
}
```

**Query by product:-**

1) Cannot use **IN operator** for partition key

2) Cannot use `batchLoad` API without knowing the sort key

**Conclusion:-**

The efficient solution is to create GSI (without sort key) on attribute `Id` and use `batchLoad` API.

**Note:** The partition key of GSI need not be unique

Comment: The ID query can be handled with the GSI, but did we conclude that querying products with the IN operator (and no other columns) is not possible? If so, would removing ID as the sort key of the table be a solution to allow the batch API? Or are there any other options except full scan?

Comment: @notionquest Is it possible to use batchLoad with the GSI ?