# how to use in operator in dynamodb using Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

How can we query on a table in DynamoDB with IN clause using Python?

I have users table, Here is schema[username is Partition key]:

```
{
    username:"ABC_15",
    password:"1234",
    company: "15",
     Id    :  ABC
}
```

I want to query like SQL :

Select * from users where id in ('ABC','XYZ','FGH')

and id is not a Partitionkey in table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476496/query-dynamodb-with-in-clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query DynamoDB with IN Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476496/query-dynamodb-with-in-clause)

Comment: That is in java, I need in python.

Comment: Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Did you try creating a global secondary index(GSI) ? You cannot query for anything other than partition key in dynamodb unless you have defined a global secondary index. Make `ID` as a GSI and then query with it. Please note that to update the table again you need primary key. You cannot update the table using GSI.

Comment: If you can Provide any Sample code , That will be Very Helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I am using below code, is there any other option avilable:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
table = dynamodb.Table('users_setup')
users1 = "ABC,XYZ"
print(users1)
users = users1.split(',')

try:
    response = table.scan(
        
            FilterExpression=Attr('id').is_in(users) 
        
    )
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    items = response['Items']
    print(items)
    print("Scan succeeded:")
```